# CMS functionality for OpenERP 7

Tags: cms, openerp

I'm looking for a CMS module for OpenERP 7. What I need is a way to create public pages, which are "decoupled" from the standard OpenERP layout. What I mean by this is that the pages should look like any page (think Wordpress/Joomla!) and not like an OpenERP module.

Oh, and I'm not looking for a wiki or anything like that. Think public website tool for a small company.

Comment: Hi, welcome. We don't do webapps such as OpenERP here. You're better of asking this kind of question on WebApps.Stackexchange.com (where it will likely be migrated) or on an OpenERP user forum. Please read [ask] before asking a question next time.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll look into the How To Ask document. Perhaps the tag 'openerp' should be removed, if you don't support it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a cms module in openerp 8. Not released, but it runs openerp.com. See their blog for details, post about the launch of version 7:
http://v6.openerp.com/node/1329

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.